# Is the sixth-gen iPod classic compatible with recent Sony Dockstations?

Tags: ipod, hardware, third-party

I have a 6th-gen iPod classic (the first model classic) with an 80 GB hard drive. I have recently purchased a Sony Dockstation for iPods but I cannot make it work. Every time it connects to the dock, an Apple symbol comes up. Can anyone explain what should I do to make it work?

Comment: Could you edit the question to include the exact model number of (or a link to) your Dockstation? That should make the issue easier to troubleshoot. Thanks!

Comment: @Carina The first generation of iPods didn't have anywhere near 80 GB of storage or a dock connector. The only iPods with 80 GB drives were the Late-2006 iPod (commonly called 5.5-generation) and the first iPod classic (commonly called the 6th-gen iPod). I've edited your question assuming the latter is correct, please change it if the former is correct.